# Confusion in some ReactNative stuff

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, react-native-ios

Below is the code for React Native enviorment.
I can see that A main Component App is created.
It has state inside it. But, Confused that what the actual purpose of using state.

```
 import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         data: 
         [
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"Foo",
               "age":"20"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "name":"Bar",
               "age":"30"
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "name":"Baz",
               "age":"40"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Header/>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  {this.state.data.map((person, i) => <TableRow key = {i} 
                     data = {person} />)}
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Header</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
class TableRow extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <tr>
            <td>{this.props.data.id}</td>
            <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.data.age}</td>
         </tr>
      );
   }
}
export default App
```

Got idea about **Header** and **TableRow** components inside main **App** component. 
But, confused with below lines :

```
{this.state.data.map((person, i) => <TableRow key = {i} 
                 data = {person} />)}
```

Anybody can explain the working of above syntax ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are wondering why React Native is using state. you should take a look on this document which was owned by Facebook `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state` and do the example, then it will help you clearly your mind.
- For answering the your sample code:

  `{this.state.data.map((person, i) => <TableRow key = {i} data = {person} />)}`

  - First it get the data from variable state `map` and loop through it to render every row View. if you do some trigger to change the data like `this.setState({data: []})`, it will change the view to empty and refresh the View automatically and it will answer why the state is using in. =))

It is pretty simple!

Comment: Where and by which the iteration is happenning ?

Comment: .map() here is Javascript function and above code maybe make you confused. it should be this `this.state.map((person, i) => {  
    return (<View>blah blah</View>)})`. Then you can debug in arrow function.